How can I solve the out-of-range percentage issue for sliders?
I created a simple slider that controls the position of a red circle on the screen within a predefined area. Moving the circle on the screen also moves the slider knob. However, the slider knob has a limited range of movement, from -1.0 to 1.0. When the circle crosses the blue border, the slider logic prevents the knob from sliding further to match the circle's new position.
I’ve been struggling with this issue for days and have tried different approaches, but none have met my requirements. I need to know the logical way (or ways) to handle situations like this, where the slider reaches its maximum range and cannot respond to further movement. How can this issue be resolved in a way that addresses the exhausted slider position rather than preventing it from happening?
PS: I have to say, this extra movement of the circle could be any value, whether big or small.
Also: Slider value of +1.0 means the circle is inside the boundary on the right side, any extra drag of circle beyond that point would still keep the slider at +1.0, but now this +1.0 would correspond to the circle being outside the boundary. While slider value of -1.0 means the boundary on the left side.
Code for iOS 15.0, macOS 12.0
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    private let maxCanvasVisibilitySize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 400.0, height: 300.0)
    private let circleSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
    
    @State private var maxCanvasImaginarySize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 400.0, height: 300.0)

    @State private var circleLastOffset: CGSize = CGSize()
    @State private var circleCurrentOffset: CGSize = CGSize()
    @State private var circleIsDragging: Bool = Bool()
    
    @State private var percentage: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack {
            
            GeometryReader { geometryValue in
                
                ZStack {
                    
                    Color.black
                    
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.red)
                        .frame(width: circleSize.width, height: circleSize.height)
                        .offset(circleCurrentOffset)
                        .gesture(circleDragGesture)
                    
                }
                .overlay(Rectangle().stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4.0))
                
            }
            .frame(width: maxCanvasVisibilitySize.width, height: maxCanvasVisibilitySize.height)
            
            SliderView(percentage: $percentage)
                .frame(width: maxCanvasVisibilitySize.width)
            
        }
        .padding()
        .onChange(of: percentage) { newValue in
            if (!circleIsDragging) {
                circleCurrentOffset.width = newValue * ((maxCanvasVisibilitySize.width - circleSize.width)/2.0)
                circleLastOffset = circleCurrentOffset
                
            }
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
    private var circleDragGesture: some Gesture {
        
        return DragGesture(minimumDistance: CGFloat.zero, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onChanged() { gestureValue in
                
                circleIsDragging = true
                
                circleCurrentOffset = CGSize(width: gestureValue.translation.width + circleLastOffset.width,
                                             height: gestureValue.translation.height + circleLastOffset.height)
                
                percentage = circleCurrentOffset.width/((maxCanvasVisibilitySize.width - circleSize.width)/2.0)
                
                
                
            }
            .onEnded() { gestureValue in
                circleLastOffset = circleCurrentOffset
                circleIsDragging = false
            }
        
    }
}


struct SliderView: View {
    
    init(percentage: Binding<CGFloat>) {
        self._percentage = percentage
    }
    
    @Binding var percentage: CGFloat
    
    @State private var knobLastOffset: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    @State private var knobCurrentOffset: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    @State private var knobIsDragging: Bool = Bool()
    
    private let knobSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 50.0, height: 30.0)
    
    @State private var sliderGeometrySize: CGSize = CGSize()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometryValue in
            
            ZStack {
                
                Color.white
                
                Color.blue.opacity(0.75)
                    .frame(width: knobSize.width)
                    .offset(x: knobCurrentOffset)
                    .gesture(knobDragGesture)
                
            }
            .onAppear { sliderGeometrySize = geometryValue.size }
            .onChange(of: geometryValue.size) { newValue in
                sliderGeometrySize = newValue
                
                let upperRangeOffset = (newValue.width - knobSize.width)/2.0
                let lowerRangeOffset = -upperRangeOffset
                
                knobCurrentOffset = offsetRegulatorWithPercentage(percentage: percentage, upperRangeOffset: upperRangeOffset, lowerRangeOffset: lowerRangeOffset)
                knobLastOffset = knobCurrentOffset
                
            }
            
        }
        .frame(height: knobSize.height)
        .onChange(of: percentage) { newValue in
            if (!knobIsDragging) {
                
                let upperRangeOffset = (sliderGeometrySize.width - knobSize.width)/2.0
                let lowerRangeOffset = -upperRangeOffset
                
                knobCurrentOffset = offsetRegulatorWithPercentage(percentage: newValue, upperRangeOffset: upperRangeOffset, lowerRangeOffset: lowerRangeOffset)
                knobLastOffset = knobCurrentOffset
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    private var knobDragGesture: some Gesture {
        
        return DragGesture(minimumDistance: CGFloat.zero, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onChanged() { gestureValue in
                
                knobIsDragging = true
                let internalOffset = gestureValue.translation.width + knobLastOffset
                let upperRangeOffset = (sliderGeometrySize.width - knobSize.width)/2.0
                let lowerRangeOffset = -upperRangeOffset
                
                knobCurrentOffset = offsetRegulator(internalOffset: internalOffset, upperRangeOffset: upperRangeOffset, lowerRangeOffset: lowerRangeOffset)
                percentage = knobCurrentOffset / ((sliderGeometrySize.width - knobSize.width)/2.0)
                
            }
            .onEnded() { gestureValue in
                knobLastOffset = knobCurrentOffset
                knobIsDragging = false
            }
        
    }
    
    private func offsetRegulator(internalOffset: CGFloat, upperRangeOffset: CGFloat, lowerRangeOffset: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        
        if (internalOffset >= .zero) {
            
            if (internalOffset < upperRangeOffset)  {
                return internalOffset
            }
            else {
                return upperRangeOffset
            }
            
        }
        else {
            
            if (internalOffset > lowerRangeOffset)  {
                return internalOffset
            }
            else {
                return lowerRangeOffset
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    private func offsetRegulatorWithPercentage(percentage: CGFloat, upperRangeOffset: CGFloat, lowerRangeOffset: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let internalOffset: CGFloat = percentage * upperRangeOffset
        return offsetRegulator(internalOffset: internalOffset, upperRangeOffset: upperRangeOffset, lowerRangeOffset: lowerRangeOffset)
        
    }
}




The behavior you show seems pretty reasonable for an "out of bounds" condition. Why don't you block the user from dragging the circle out of bounds and call it a day?

If you don't want to do that, you could have your slider's min and max values describe the absolute limits of your circle (the screen boundaries) and then put an overlay on top of the slider with tick marks showing the "in range" limits. Dragging up to a tick-mark would move the circle to the edge of the black rectangle, and dragging past a tick-mark would move the circle outside the rectangle

The black screen serves as a canvas with a predefined size, but the user can change this limitation if desired. As a result, I can't restrict the area where the circle can move.

Then have your slider(s) extend across the entire screen, with marks at the canvas boundaries.

I read your question a few times, but it's still not clear to me what you are trying to figure out. If the slider's purpose is to position the circle horizontally within the canvas, but also reflect the position of the circle if moved by dragging without using the slider, then the circle should not be able to be dragged outside the canvas. If the canvas size changes, the slider limits should also change accordingly. Feels like this is more about understanding the logic of the use case, rather than coming up with solutions for problems that maybe shouldn't exist in the first place.

I also think that if the canvas size increases, the slider limits should adjust as well. However, this change shouldn't be visible to users. Internally, we can update the slider's limits. For example, if the circle crosses the blue line, the farthest position the circle reaches can be used as the new size for calculations.

If the canvas is the black area and the canvas increases, the black area should increase, which would also increase the slider limits. If the circle crosses the blue line is off canvas. It would make no sense for the slider limits (and consequently the knob of the slider) to suddenly jump if the circle is outside the blue line and then jump back when the circle reenters the black area - unless the black canvas automatically and visually resizes to expand up to and including the red circles, with the slider also adjusting accordingly.

I think the code is okay in its current state. What I'm thinking is that the slider should play the role of defining a value range between -1.0 and +1.0. This value change can then be used to move the circle from the far right boundary (beyond the canvas) to the left edge of the canvas. In other words, depending on the circle's position in the view, the -1.0 and +1.0 values of the slider would correspond to different positions within this range.

So if a slider value of +1.0 means the circle is inside the boundary on the right side, any extra drag of circle beyond that point would still keep the slider at +1.0, but now this +1.0 would correspond to the circle being outside the boundary.
